# SQL ORA-02063 - How to fix this?

Tags: sql, oracle

"Oracle database error 904: ORA-00904: "A6"."mn:EVENT_TS:ok": invalid identifier ORA-02063: preceding line from BIQ_Z1PC"

```
SELECT "t0"."TEMP(Calculation_1012184020205" AS 
"TEMP(Calculation_1012184020205",
"t3"."__measure__2" AS "TEMP(Calculation_1103944862926",
"t3"."__measure__4" AS "TEMP(Calculation_1103944862921",
"t0"."TEMP(Calculation_8523062336790" AS "TEMP(Calculation_8523062336790",
"t0"."mn:EVENT_TS:ok" AS "mn:EVENT_TS:ok",
"t0"."usr:Calculation_10121840202058" AS "usr:Calculation_10121840202058",
"t0"."usr:Calculation_85230623367908" AS "usr:Calculation_85230623367908"
FROM (
SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(CAST("AQE Source Data 5.30.2018"."EVENT_TS" 
AS 
DATE)),'MM')) AS "mn:EVENT_TS:ok",
COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN ("AQE Source Data 5.30.2018"."DISPO_CD" IS NULL 
AND ("AQE Source Data 5.30.2018"."CUZ_AREA_ID" <> '0_DEFECTS') AND (NOT 
(SUBSTR("AQE Source Data 5.30.2018"."EVENT_DESC", 1, LENGTH('0')) = '0')) 
AND ("AQE Source Data 5.30.2018"."QUALITY_VELOCITY" = 'Q') AND (INSTR("AQE 
Source Data 5.30.2018"."DISC_AREA_DESC",'PDI') > 0)) THEN "AQE Source Data 
5.30.2018"."EVENT_NO" ELSE NULL END)) AS "TEMP(Calculation_1012184020205",
COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN (("400 Machines"."MIN(DISC_AREA_ID)" = '400') OR 
("400 Machines"."MIN(DISC_AREA_ID)" = '450')) THEN "400 Machines"."SER_NO" 
ELSE NULL END)) AS "TEMP(Calculation_8523062336790",
COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN ("AQE Source Data 5.30.2018"."DISPO_CD" IS NULL 
AND ("AQE Source Data 5.30.2018"."CUZ_AREA_ID" <> '0_DEFECTS') AND (NOT 
(SUBSTR("AQE Source Data 5.30.2018"."EVENT_DESC", 1, LENGTH('0')) = '0')) 
AND ("AQE Source Data 5.30.2018"."QUALITY_VELOCITY" = 'Q') AND (INSTR("AQE 
Source Data 5.30.2018"."DISC_AREA_DESC",'PDI') > 0)) THEN "AQE Source Data 
5.30.2018"."EVENT_NO" ELSE NULL END)) AS "usr:Calculation_10121840202058",
COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN (("400 Machines"."MIN(DISC_AREA_ID)" = '400') OR 
("400 Machines"."MIN(DISC_AREA_ID)" = '450')) THEN "400 Machines"."SER_NO" 
ELSE NULL END)) AS "usr:Calculation_85230623367908"
FROM (
SELECT EVENT_TS, 

EVENT_NO,FAC_PROD_FAM_CD,SER_PFX,SER_NO,CUZ_AREA_ID,CUZ_AREA_DESC,
DISC_AREA_ID,  
DISC_AREA_DESC,EVENT_DESC,QUALITY_VELOCITY,ASGN_TO,FIXER_1,PD_ID,
EVENT_CAT_ID_NO,EVENT_CID_DESC_TXT,CMPNT_SERIAL_NO,NEW_FOUND_MISSED,
MISSED_AREA_ID,RPR_MIN,WAIT_TIME,DISPO_CD,PROTOTYPE_IND,EXT_CPY_STAT,
CLSE_STAT,CLSE_TS,CAUSE_SHIFT,DEF_WELD_ INC,WELD_SEAM_ID
FROM
ABUS_DW.V_BIQ_R8_QWB_EVENTS
WHERE
(FAC_PROD_FAM_CD='ACOM' OR FAC_PROD_FAM_CD='SCOM' OR FAC_PROD_FAM_CD='LAP' 
OR FAC_PROD_FAM_CD='RM' OR FAC_PROD_FAM_CD='SCRD') 
AND (DISC_AREA_ID<>'501' AND DISC_AREA_ID<>'525' AND DISC_AREA_ID<>'600' AND 
DISC_AREA_ID<>'700' AND DISC_AREA_ID<>'701' AND DISC_AREA_ID<>'702' AND 
DISC_AREA_ID<>'703' AND DISC_AREA_ID<>'704' AND 
DISC_AREA_ID<>'705' AND DISC_AREA_ID<>'706' AND DISC_AREA_ID<>'707' AND 
DISC_AREA_ID<>'800' AND DISC_AREA_ID<>'900')
AND PROTOTYPE_IND<>'Y' AND EXT_CPY_STAT<>'D' AND
EVENT_TS>=TO_DATE('2015-10-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
) "AQE Source Data 5.30.2018"
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT DISTINCT
MIN(EVENT_TS), MIN(EVENT_NO), MIN(DISC_AREA_ID), MIN(DISC_AREA_DESC), 
MIN(EVENT_DESC), MIN(EXT_CPY_STAT), MIN(FAC_PROD_FAM_CD), SER_NO, 
PROTOTYPE_IND
FROM ABUS_DW.V_BIQ_R8_QWB_EVENTS
WHERE
(FAC_PROD_FAM_CD='ACOM' OR FAC_PROD_FAM_CD='SCOM' OR FAC_PROD_FAM_CD='LAP' 
OR FAC_PROD_FAM_CD='RM' OR FAC_PROD_FAM_CD='SCRD')
AND (DISC_AREA_ID='400' OR DISC_AREA_ID='450')
AND PROTOTYPE_IND<>'Y' AND EXT_CPY_STAT<>'D' AND EVENT_TS>=TO_DATE('2015-10- 
01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY
SER_NO, PROTOTYPE_IND
) "400 Machines" ON ("AQE Source Data 5.30.2018"."EVENT_NO" = "400 
Machines"."MIN(EVENT_NO)")
WHERE (TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(CAST("AQE Source Data 5.30.2018"."EVENT_TS" 
AS DATE)),'YYYY')) = 2018)
GROUP BY TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(CAST("AQE Source Data 5.30.2018"."EVENT_TS" 
AS DATE)),'MM'))
) "t0"
INNER JOIN (
SELECT "t1"."mn:EVENT_TS:ok" AS "mn:EVENT_TS:ok",
SUM("t2"."__measure__1") AS "__measure__2",
SUM((CASE WHEN ("t2"."__measure__3" > 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS 
"__measure__4"
 FROM (
SELECT "400 Machines"."SER_NO" AS "SER_NO (Custom SQL Query)",
TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(CAST("AQE Source Data 5.30.2018"."EVENT_TS" AS 
DATE)),'MM')) AS "mn:EVENT_TS:ok"
FROM (
SELECT

EVENT_TS,EVENT_NO,FAC_PROD_FAM_CD,SER_PFX,SER_NO,CUZ_AREA_ID,
CUZ_AREA_DESC,DISC_AREA_ID,DISC_AREA_DESC,EVENT_DESC,QUALITY_VELOCITY,
ASGN_TO,FIXER_1,PD_ID,EVENT_CAT_ID_NO,
EVENT_CID_DESC_TXT,CMPNT_SERIAL_NO,NEW_FOUND_MISSED,MISSED_AREA_ID,
RPR_MIN,WAIT_TIME,DISPO_CD,PROTOTYPE_IND,EXT_CPY_STAT,CLSE_STAT,CLSE_TS,
CAUSE_SHIFT,DEF_WELD_INC,WELD_SEAM_ID
FROM
ABUS_DW.V_BIQ_R8_QWB_EVENTS
WHERE
(FAC_PROD_FAM_CD='ACOM' OR FAC_PROD_FAM_CD='SCOM' OR FAC_PROD_FAM_CD='LAP' 
OR FAC_PROD_FAM_CD='RM' OR FAC_PROD_FAM_CD='SCRD') 
AND (DISC_AREA_ID<>'501' AND DISC_AREA_ID<>'525' AND DISC_AREA_ID<>'600' AND 
DISC_AREA_ID<>'700' AND DISC_AREA_ID<>'701' AND DISC_AREA_ID<>'702' AND 
DISC_AREA_ID<>'703' AND DISC_AREA_ID<>'704' AND 
DISC_AREA_ID<>'705' AND DISC_AREA_ID<>'706' AND DISC_AREA_ID<>'707' AND 
DISC_AREA_ID<>'800' AND DISC_AREA_ID<>'900')
AND PROTOTYPE_IND<>'Y' AND EXT_CPY_STAT<>'D' AND
EVENT_TS>=TO_DATE('2015-10-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
) "AQE Source Data 5.30.2018"
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT DISTINCT
MIN(EVENT_TS), MIN(EVENT_NO), MIN(DISC_AREA_ID), MIN(DISC_AREA_DESC), 
MIN(EVENT_DESC), MIN(EXT_CPY_STAT), MIN(FAC_PROD_FAM_CD), SER_NO, 
PROTOTYPE_IND
FROM ABUS_DW.V_BIQ_R8_QWB_EVENTS
WHERE
(FAC_PROD_FAM_CD='ACOM' OR FAC_PROD_FAM_CD='SCOM' OR FAC_PROD_FAM_CD='LAP' 
OR FAC_PROD_FAM_CD='RM' OR FAC_PROD_FAM_CD='SCRD')
AND (DISC_AREA_ID='400' OR DISC_AREA_ID='450')
AND PROTOTYPE_IND<>'Y' AND EXT_CPY_STAT<>'D' AND EVENT_TS>=TO_DATE('2015-10- 
01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY
SER_NO, PROTOTYPE_IND
) "400 Machines" ON ("AQE Source Data 5.30.2018"."EVENT_NO" = "400 
Machines"."MIN(EVENT_NO)")
WHERE (TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(CAST("AQE Source Data 5.30.2018"."EVENT_TS" 
AS DATE)),'YYYY')) = 2018)
GROUP BY "400 Machines"."SER_NO",
TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(CAST("AQE Source Data 5.30.2018"."EVENT_TS" AS 
DATE)),'MM'))
) "t1"
INNER JOIN (
SELECT "400 Machines"."SER_NO" AS "SER_NO (Custom SQL Query)",
COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN ((CASE WHEN (INSTR("AQE Source Data 
5.30.2018"."DISC_AREA_DESC",'PDI') > 0) THEN 1 WHEN (("AQE Source Data 
5.30.2018"."DISC_AREA_ID" = '500') AND ("AQE Source Data 
5.30.2018"."QUALITY_VELOCITY" = 'Q')) THEN 2 ELSE NULL END) = 1) THEN "AQE 
Source Data 5.30.2018"."SER_NO" WHEN NOT ((CASE WHEN (INSTR("AQE Source Data 
5.30.2018"."DISC_AREA_DESC",'PDI') > 0) THEN 1 WHEN (("AQE Source Data 
5.30.2018"."DISC_AREA_ID" = '500') AND ("AQE Source Data 
5.30.2018"."QUALITY_VELOCITY" = 'Q')) THEN 2 ELSE NULL END) = 1) THEN NULL 
ELSE NULL END)) AS "__measure__1",
COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN ("AQE Source Data 5.30.2018"."DISPO_CD" IS NULL 
AND ("AQE Source Data 5.30.2018"."CUZ_AREA_ID" <> '0_DEFECTS') AND (NOT 
(SUBSTR("AQE Source Data 5.30.2018"."EVENT_DESC", 1, LENGTH('0')) = '0')) 
AND ("AQE Source Data 5.30.2018"."DISC_AREA_ID" = '400')) THEN "AQE Source 
Data 5.30.2018"."EVENT_NO" ELSE NULL END)) AS "__measure__3"
FROM (
SELECT
EVENT_TS,EVENT_NO,FAC_PROD_FAM_CD,SER_PFX,SER_NO,CUZ_AREA_ID,
CUZ_AREA_DESC,DISC_AREA_ID,DISC_AREA_DESC,EVENT_DESC,QUALITY_VELOCITY,
ASGN_TO,FIXER_1,PD_ID,EVENT_CAT_ID_NO,
EVENT_CID_DESC_TXT,CMPNT_SERIAL_NO,NEW_FOUND_MISSED,MISSED_AREA_ID,
RPR_MIN,WAIT_TIME,DISPO_CD,PROTOTYPE_IND,EXT_CPY_STAT,CLSE_STAT,CLSE_TS,
CAUSE_SHIFT,DEF_WELD_INC,WELD_SEAM_ID
FROM
ABUS_DW.V_BIQ_R8_QWB_EVENTS
WHERE
(FAC_PROD_FAM_CD='ACOM' OR FAC_PROD_FAM_CD='SCOM' OR FAC_PROD_FAM_CD='LAP' 
OR FAC_PROD_FAM_CD='RM' OR FAC_PROD_FAM_CD='SCRD') 
AND (DISC_AREA_ID<>'501' AND DISC_AREA_ID<>'525' AND DISC_AREA_ID<>'600'
AND DISC_AREA_ID<>'700' AND DISC_AREA_ID<>'701' AND DISC_AREA_ID<>'702' AND 
DISC_AREA_ID<>'703' AND DISC_AREA_ID<>'704' AND 
DISC_AREA_ID<>'705' AND DISC_AREA_ID<>'706' AND DISC_AREA_ID<>'707' AND 
DISC_AREA_ID<>'800' AND DISC_AREA_ID<>'900')
AND PROTOTYPE_IND<>'Y' AND EXT_CPY_STAT<>'D' AND
EVENT_TS>=TO_DATE('2015-10-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
) "AQE Source Data 5.30.2018"
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT DISTINCT
MIN(EVENT_TS), MIN(EVENT_NO), MIN(DISC_AREA_ID), MIN(DISC_AREA_DESC), 
MIN(EVENT_DESC), MIN(EXT_CPY_STAT), MIN(FAC_PROD_FAM_CD), SER_NO,
PROTOTYPE_IND
FROM ABUS_DW.V_BIQ_R8_QWB_EVENTS
WHERE
(FAC_PROD_FAM_CD='ACOM' OR FAC_PROD_FAM_CD='SCOM' OR FAC_PROD_FAM_CD='LAP' 
OR FAC_PROD_FAM_CD='RM' OR FAC_PROD_FAM_CD='SCRD')
AND (DISC_AREA_ID='400' OR DISC_AREA_ID='450')
AND PROTOTYPE_IND<>'Y' AND EXT_CPY_STAT<>'D' AND EVENT_TS>=TO_DATE(
'2015-10- 01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY
SER_NO, PROTOTYPE_IND
) "400 Machines" ON ("AQE Source Data 5.30.2018"."EVENT_NO" = "400 
Machines"."MIN(EVENT_NO)")
GROUP BY "400 Machines"."SER_NO"
) "t2" ON (("t1"."SER_NO (Custom SQL Query)" = "t2"."SER_NO (Custom SQL 
Query)") OR (("t1"."SER_NO (Custom SQL Query)" IS NULL) AND ("t2"."SER_NO 
(Custom SQL Query)" IS NULL)))
GROUP BY "t1"."mn:EVENT_TS:ok"
) "t3" ON (("t0"."mn:EVENT_TS:ok" = "t3"."mn:EVENT_TS:ok") OR 
(("t0"."mn:EVENT_TS:ok" IS NULL) AND ("t3"."mn:EVENT_TS:ok" IS NULL)))
```

Comment: Formatting is the first step to enlightenment...

Comment: com'on man help

Comment: What did you find when you researched that error message and searched your code for BIQ_Z1PC?

Comment: @StevieG I can't even find these columns in your code anywhere so it's going to be an uphill battle. Maybe one of the oracle professionals can give you more insight.

Comment: BIQ_Z1PC is the database I'm connected to... it's just an identifier

Comment: @JacobH this is just how it gave it to me when I copied the error to the clipboard... I know nothing about how to fix this, but I've spent so much time developing this, I can't just start over

Comment: @StevieG Do some work on this and come back. Don't dump 200 lines of code and ask for help. Research that error code and message, find the error chunk of code, then find the line, then troubleshoot. When you have a narrow question about how to fix it, repost. You admitted to knowing nothing about how to fix this, which means you have done no research before asking others to do your work for you.

Comment: Maybe create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I doubt anyone would be willing to analyze this monster.

Comment: Remove everything from WHERE to the end and see if it still throws the error. If it does, the problem is in the first half and if not, it's in the second. Nobody is going to be able to give you a lot of help on this, aside from "you have a bad identifier". Maybe you spelled it wrong, maybe you're querying the wrong tables. It could be almost anything.

Comment: @JacobH this is the error line "mn:EVENT_TS:ok" AS "mn:EVENT_TS:ok", but knowing nothing about SQL I don't even know what it's trying to tell me... I've already looked up the error code and the best explanation I found was 

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_02063_preceding_stringstring_from_stringstring.htm

Comment: Yeah I figured no one could help... its the calculation I'm running and what it's referencing... or specifically how it's referencing it... everything else works... this is just a very necessary component.  Thanks tho

Comment: There are several instances of `"mn:EVENT_TS:ok"`, but no `A6`. The one you mention (where it helpfully aliases `"mn:EVENT_TS:ok"` as `"mn:EVENT_TS:ok"` is in `"t1"` (and `"t1"` does have that column).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be the blank space in `DEF_WELD_ INC`, which should be `DEF_WELD_INC`. I created a table `v_biq_r8_qwb_events` to match the columns expected by subquery `"AQE Source Data 5.30.2018"`, removed the line breaks in things like

```
ON ("AQE Source Data 5.30.2018"."EVENT_NO" = "400 
Machines"."MIN(EVENT_NO)")
```

which I'm assuming should be

```
ON ("AQE Source Data 5.30.2018"."EVENT_NO" = "400 Machines"."MIN(EVENT_NO)")
```

and that was the only error.

Answer (score 0):

Double quoted strings are identifiers in the select, you can use them to preserve case in the AS portion, but in the select list they are identifiers.
This looks like really awful machine generated sql for something other than oracle, and not complete.

Comment: Tableau auto-generated this crap